# smtp timeout from python client in rancher container

Tags: docker, mailgun, smtplib, rancher

I have a weird issue with no ideas what could be wrong, so maybe writing it here can help me come up with ideas. Or someone can help me :)

I have a Django site running in rancher and for past few weeks I noticed emails are not working. Timeout error is raised. I am using mailgun.org as SMTP server.

This is output from rancher container console:

```
/app/app # ipython
Python 2.7.14 (default, Dec 19 2017, 22:36:09)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from smtplib import SMTP

In [2]: smtp = SMTP(host='smtp.mailgun.org', port=587)
```

And it just hangs. Adding timeout raises timeout of course.

I would guess there is something wrong with mailgun. But running same code on same image locally works (`commit-hash` matches the one on rancher container).

```
docker run -ti registry.gitlab.com/namespace/app:commit-hash /bin/sh
/app/app # ipython
Python 2.7.14 (default, Dec 19 2017, 22:36:09)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from smtplib import SMTP

In [2]: smtp = SMTP(host='smtp.mailgun.org', port=587)

In [3]:
```

I do not get how it works. I contacted mailgun support with a question if they block my server's ip address. Their answer:

> We are not blocking the production IP.  The only way one environment
>   can work and not another is that there is some aspect of your two
>   environments that is different, so we would recommend reviewing the
>   configurations on your side.

What can be different there if I am using same docker image? Only way I alter environment are env variables, but none of them are related to python/system.

I thought error was cased by me using gevent, but I removed it yesterday.

---

> Please try "telnet smtp.mailgun.org 587" in docker console

```
/app/app # telnet smtp.mailgun.org 587
telnet: can't connect to remote host (52.10.40.100): Operation timed out
/app/app #
```

first lines of Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install dependencies
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache build-base \
        curl \
        nano \
        postgresql-dev \
        vim
```

telnet from host machine:

```
~# telnet smtp.mailgun.org 587
Trying 34.232.180.42...
Trying 54.164.235.211...
Trying 34.237.7.101...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Please try "telnet smtp.mailgun.org 587" in docker console and post the result

Comment: @ffeast added to question

Comment: Looks like outgoing port 587 is blocked on way to `smtp.mailgun.org`. Can you try the same `telnet` command from the host where container is?

Comment: timeouting as well, added to original question. Will contact hosting provider if they are blocking that port

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Hello,
>
> In order to respond favorably to your request to unblock port 25 of your server, an additional verification is necessary.
>   ...

Looks like provider (Scaleway.com) blocked that port.

I had no idea hosting companies are doing this, when I was using external service for email. Anyway, verified my account, disabled blocking, hard-rebooted server and it works.

Thanks you all for comments/help!